# How to create multiple instances of IIS for multiple Visual Studio instances on the same server instance?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, iis

Now we have a Windows server on the virtual machine that should be accessed by multiple users/accounts, each user will start his/her own Visual Studio instance.

Problem here is when every one working on the same web application (connecting to the single IIS server instance), all Visual Studio instances are somewhat correlated to each other so that if one instance is freeze and removed from task manager, all other instances are gone as well.

So the question is how to create multiple IIS instances on the same Windows server so instance can be used for a single connection, just like the connection pool as such..

Comment: Q: If multiple developers are coding a web app on their local workstations ... then why not use the local IIS that comes built-in with MSVS?  Exactly what "shared resource(s)" does the IIS instance need from "the server"?

Comment: @paulsm4 Sorry may be I made confusion here. There is no local workstation. Every developer has a separate account in the Windows Server so they work in the same remote workstation.

Comment: Microsoft didn't plan that scenario well, so there is always a single IIS server. Either you set up virtual machines for each developers, or you ask them to work on individual sites.

Comment: I agree with Lex, here is a workaround, if you want to everyone's environment doesn't affect other one's application, I suggest you could consider using docker. As far as I know visual studio support testing the application on the docker, Detaisl, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/overview?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @BrandoZhang & LexiLi Thank you for the kind follow up. I appreciate the advice of using Docker. So then what shall we put in docker? The entire IIS server instance? Also how does that affect the licensing of IIS?

Comment: If you use docker, you just need to add a IIS container. [Link](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/). Details about how to use docker, I suggest you could refer to this [article](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/).

Comment: @Brando Zhang Thanks! Sounds like it's ok to create container for each user from IIS image?

Comment: Yes, each user could create its own container. They could modify its own container. Each container will not affect other ones.